# Is Content Query Web Part available on SharePoint 2016 standard edition

Tags: content-query-web-part

Please advise if Content Query web part is available on SharePoint 2016 - standard edition.
Thanks much!

Comment: are you using publishing site ?

Answer (score 2):

Based on this article [Simply, What’s new and deprecated features in SharePoint Server 2016 ?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/16/whats-new-in-sharepoint-and-project-server-2016-in-simple-words/) it's not a deprecated feature

So it's should be shown at publishing site .

If you are using team site try to activate `SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure` and `SharePoint Server Publishing`

- On the Site Collection Features page, click the Activate button next to SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure.

[image]

- On site feature , activate SharePoint Server Publishing .

[image]

Once this feature has been activated, the Content Query Web Part should then be available throughout the Site Collection.

[image]

For more info check [My Content Query Web Part Is Missing!](https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/my-content-query-web-part-is-missing/)

Comment: @sandy - do you get it working?

Comment: when activate publishing feature, its showing content search webpart but content query is still missing.

Comment: What is your SharePoint edition?

Comment: I am using enterprise version. Finally found that webpart in default group. Don't know why its showing there.